# Obtaining a list of all possible python modules on the system

Tags: python, list, package

Is there a possible way to get a list of all possible python modules on the system. For example in IDLE you can do something like `help('modules')` and obtain a sorted list of installed packages. But what I would like is to programmatically gather a list from inside of a python program. Something like:

```
possible_packages = ["os","pty","psutil",..]
```

And from there be able to parse through that list. How can I do this within a python program?

Comment: all packages installed in the OS?

Comment: @mrbTT basically what I would like to do is create a customized version of IDLE that I can run from inside of a program. This customized version would only allow certain things, etc.. So yes I would need EVERYTHING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pkgutil.walk_packages`:

```
from pkgutil import walk_packages
possible_packages = [module for _, module, _ in walk_packages()]
```